# get ip address of clients machine

Tags: c#, networking

we have 10 computers at lab, we set-up all computers connected to LAN so we
can share files, my computer serves as the main computer, i just want to get all
IP address of the computers connected to main computer(that is my computer) and list them
my code is

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = &quot;cmd &quot;;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = &quot;/C net view&quot;;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.Start();
    String output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { &#39;\n&#39;, &#39;\\&#39; };
    string[] s = output.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry IPHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
    Console.WriteLine(IPHost.HostName); // Output name of web host
    IPAddress[] address = IPHost.AddressList; // get list of IP address
    // Console.WriteLine(&quot;List IP {0} :&quot;, IPHost.HostName);
    if (address.Length &gt; 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; address.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(address[i]);
        }
    }


    p.WaitForExit();
    int z = s.Length - 5;

    string[] str1 = new string[z];
   // int i = 0;
    char[] saperator = { &#39; &#39; };
    for (int j = 3; j &lt; s.Length - 2; j++)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
       // str1[i] = (s[j].ToString()).Split(saperator)[0];
       // Console.WriteLine(&quot;IP Address {0}: {1} &quot;, i, addr[i].ToString());
    }
    //Console.WriteLine(output);

    s = output.Split(new string[] { &quot;\n,\\&quot; }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    //Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
    //Console.WriteLine(output);
   // Console.WriteLine(&quot;IP Address : {1} &quot;, i, AddressList[i].ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
```

but i get my machine's ip address ,i want to 10 machine's ip address in lab.

Comment: Could you edit your post and reformat the code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the host name, pass the result of *net view*.

```
foreach (string hostName in hostNames)
{
    //string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
    IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
    Console.WriteLine(entry.HostName); // output name of web host
    IPAddress[] addresses = entry.AddressList; // get list of IP addresses
    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(address);
    }
}
```